# How to encode data in datagridview column?

Tags: c#, encoding, datagridview

Is possible to encode the data that a column in a datagridview? The data is of type string.

Comment: What do you mean by 'encode'?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tag property for the DataGridViewColumn.